# how to solve a quadratic congruence when the modulus is not square-free

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$ x^2\equiv1\pmod {12} $

This factors out to $ x^2\equiv1\pmod {3 \cdot 4}  $

I've tried $ x^2\equiv1\pmod 3 $ and $x^2\equiv1\pmod 4 $

doesn't seem to work; how do I deal with prime squares?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you meant $3\cdot4$ or $3\cdot2^2$, not $3\cdot4^2$

Comment: Yes, I meant 4. Thank you

Comment: $x^2\equiv 1\bmod p^2 \iff p^2|x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)\iff p^2|x+1$ or $x-1 \iff x\equiv\pm1\bmod p^2$ for $p$ prime

Answer (score 1):

How to solve $x^2\equiv1\pmod {4=2^2}$:

$x^2\equiv1\pmod4\iff x^2-1\equiv0\pmod4$

$\iff4|(x+1)(x-1) \iff  2|x-1 \iff x\equiv1\pmod2$

( $\iff x\equiv1$ or $3\pmod 4$).

Now you solve $x^2\equiv1\pmod{12} $ by solving $x\equiv1\pmod2$ and $x\equiv\pm1\pmod3$.

Comment: how is $x=3(mod 4)$. I didn't understand that part

Comment: that was a side point, but if $2|x-1$ then $2|\dfrac{x-1}2$ or $2|\left(\dfrac{x-1}2-1\right)$, i.e., $4|x-1$ or $x-3$

Answer (score 0):

It's great idea to try to solve it because instead of 12 it can be much larger number. However for 12 I would use different approach:

1. Filter all even numbers because they cannot be solutions
2. Divide odd numbers into two groups: {1, 3, 5} and {-1, -3, -5}. Their solutions correspond.
3. Review cases 1, 3, 5, add the other group and get final answer.